# How do you write "castles" in algebraic?

Tags: castling, notation

Sorry if this question is a duplicate one, but I can't find the algebraic notation for castling. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either algebraic or descriptive notation, castling is notated 0-0 or O-O on the Kingside (when the King goes to g1 or g8) and 0-0-0 or O-O-O on the Queenside (when the King goes to c1 to c8).  See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)#Castling

Comment: Small addendum: In PGN, O-O is the preferred notation - some programs accept 0-0, some don't. Chessbooks may even have OO or 00. The official version is Appendix C of the FIDE rules.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean castling? 0-0 denotes kingside castling, i.e. the "short" way, and  0-0-0 is for queenside castling, i.e. the "long" way. The zeros represent the number of squares the rook travels.